# Get the Text of dynamically created button in C#?

Tags: c#

I am dynamically creating buttons in C# with this logic

```
for (int i = 1; i <= vap; ++i)
{
    newButtons[i] = new Button();
    newButtons[i].BackColor = Color.Gray;
    newButtons[i].Name = "Button4" + i.ToString();
    newButtons[i].Click += new EventHandler(NewButtons_Click);

    newButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(width,height);
    newButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(76, 38);

    tabPage5.Controls.Add(newButtons[i]);
}
```

This is creating a button and the click event is also working but my problem is I don't know how to get the text of the newly created button. On form load I am putting the text of button from database and this also happening correctly, but I want to know how to get the text of dynamically created buttons.

Comment: Have you tried `newButton[i].Text`?

Comment: in your code you are not setting the text property. once you set it, from the NewButtons_Click event you can inspect the sender parameter and you will find out it's the button itself so you can get the text back. if this does not help, explain where you plan to SET the text initially and when/where/event handler you want to GET the text back.

Comment: When do you want to get the text of the button?

Comment: I am setting the text from the database and the text is also viewed when buttons are created after form loads.
I just need the code which i should write here

Comment: private void NewButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { //IN THIS EVENT}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to get the text until after you populate it from the database (careful not to try and get the text too early).

But this should work:

```
string buttonText = FindControl("Button41").Text;
```

**Update**

Since you want the button text from within the click event, you can access the sender object:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
string buttonText = button.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the `Text` property of the button when you add it.

Answer (score 0):

Using something along the lines of...

string BtnTxt = FindControl("ExampleButton1").Text;

should work fine.

This may cause problems later on however if you are trying to pull text content of buttons in a random order.