# Get text from dynamically-generated textbox to insert with button

Tags: c#

I am creating divs with textbox and a button on each one. They are being created like this:

```
TextBox txtGosto = new TextBox();
txtGosto.ID = "txtGosto_" + postid;
```

Then, a button after it with an EventHandler to submit the text.

```
btnInsertPost.ID = "btnInsertPost_" + postid;
btnInsertPost.Click += (sender, e) => { InsertPost(sender, e, postid); };
```

The postid is working and being passed as an argument, but i am wondering how can i get the text from the dynamic generated textbox and submit it too.

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be after the txtGosto.Text property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The textbox name isn't fixed so the "Text" property can't be accessed like that from code behind, i was thinking more of FindControl or Request.Form["txtGosto" + id], but i am not being able to make it work.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288214/get-the-text-of-dynamically-created-button-in-c?rq=1

Comment: I don't really think it's a duplicate. He wants to get the text from the button itself upon clicking on it, i am trying to get the textbox text when the button is clicked and pass it to the method.